# get error report for name attribute mismatch in html tag and $_POST[] variable

Tags: php, post, drop-down-menu

I have done this several times before.But can't figure out why it's happening right now.My $_POST['user'] field which is intended to get selection data from drop down list is unfortunately not working.It remains undefined.It will be great if someone take the trouble and identify the mistakes i have done

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['user'])){
     $text=$_POST['text'];
     $selected=$_POST['user'];
     echo $selected;
     echo $text;
     }
?>

 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"  >
 <input type='text' name='text'>
<select name="users" id="users"  name='user' />
   <option value="test" style="color:#ccc;">Select user</option>
   <option value="user1">1</option>
   <option value="user2">2</option>
   <option value="user3">3</option>   
</select> 
<input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

EDITS:

after submitting with a different name attribute in select tag and in $_POST[] it is supposed to show an error.But it is showing nothing.see this image from my browser after submitting

[image]

***code with error_reporting***

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

     if(isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['users'])){
     $text=$_POST['text'];
    $selected=$_POST['users'];
    echo $selected;
     echo $text;
     }
?>

 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"  >
 <input type='text' name='text'>
<select  id="users"  name='user' />
   <option value="test" style="color:#ccc;">Select user</option>
   <option value="user1">1</option>
   <option value="user2">2</option>
   <option value="user3">3</option>   
</select> 
<input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: You're repeating the "name" attribute in `name="users" id="users"  name='user'`. Remove `name="users"`

Comment: The browser will match `name="users"` first and send the POST data as `users`. Do as @Fred-ii- says.

Comment: thanks a lot.My mistake though.But is there a  way to get this type of error report.Php didn't give any?

Comment: I should make that an answer lol

Comment: And add `htmlspecialchars()` to POST datas for security.

Comment: someone has done it already before you :D @Fred-ii-

Comment: True but my comment was first and qualifies as an answer ;-) plus telling you how to check for errors - wink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Firstly*, you're repeating the "name" attribute in `name="users" id="users"  name='user'`.

Remove `name="users"` since you are referencing `$_POST['user']`

> *thanks a lot.My mistake though.But is there a way to get this type of error report.Php didn't give any?*

**A:** There sure is. Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` which would have signaled the undefined index.

It didn't give any errors because your server isn't setup to throw errors by default.

Use the following, followed by the rest of your code.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Plus, as noted in comments:

> *add `htmlspecialchars()` to POST datas for security.*

---

**Edit:**

The reason why it's not throwing errors is that even if the name attributes are non-existant, it's what you check in the POST variables that will trigger the error. For example `$text=$_POST['text'];` will be OK, but `$text=$_POST['texts'];` will trigger an error.

The conditional statement also plays a role.

Since you have a matching POST for `users` in the conditional statement

```
if(isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['users']))
```

and `$selected=$_POST['users'];` will not throw an error.

If the conditional statement were different

```
if(isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['user']))
```

then it will throw an error if using `isset($_POST['user'])` along with `$selected=$_POST['users'];` instead of `$selected=$_POST['user'];` since it's being assigned and trying to match the conditional statement.

Comment: i have added a false name to check whether the error reporting works or not.But it didn' t trigger

Comment: @al-Zami you'll need to give me an **exact** example, including how it's being referenced.

Comment: consider the code i have provided in question section add those two lines of error handling code.But it didn't give me any notifications.I am not experienced in php though

Comment: You're probably using this with something else and not telling/showing us. I tested this, no problem. Least, from the code you "posted" and my fix. Again, I need an example. You're not helping me in order for me to help "you".

Comment: check my edits ,i tried to describe it as clearly as possible

Comment: @al-Zami Ok. The reason why it's not throwing errors is that even if the name attributes are non-existant, it's what you check in the POST variables that will trigger the error. For example `$text=$_POST['text'];` will be OK, but `$text=$_POST['texts'];` will trigger an error. See "my" edit to reflect this comment.

Comment: @al-Zami I've made a few more edits in the past few minutes and believe I have answered your question entirely. Reload it to see the changes under **Edit**.

Comment: What i've understand is  inside first () of  if condition ,name mismatch will not give an error but inside second {} ,it will give error.I could be better if i could get error before entering the conditonal

Comment: @al-Zami It doesn't matter. The conditional statement does play a role, but it's the variables assignment that matters the most. If it doesn't match what you've set in your conditional statement, then that's where it will throw an error. If you want to check "before", then you'd most likely need to use JS/Ajax and `isset()` with a ternary operator in the "value".

Answer (score 1):

You are using incorrect index to get dropdown selected value.

use `$_POST['users']` to get the selected value